# ajaxForm is not working and not returning error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload, ajaxform

I get a very weird problem when I want to use jQuery ajaxForm.

I want to set form and upload file with having progress percent.

my ajaxForm function is not fire at all.

here is my code but I cant find out where is the problem because I get no error.

```js
function recieve(res,obj)
{
 var frm = res.substr(1,res.length-8);
 $('#'+frm).find('.error').each(function(){ $(this).remove(); });
 if(obj['alert']!=undefined) $(res).html(obj['alert']);
 if(obj['field']!=undefined) {
  for(var i in obj['field'])
  {
   /*$("#"+i).next('.error').remove();*/
   if(obj['field'][i]!='') $("#"+i).after('<div class="error avesome OC OBC">'+obj['field'][i]+'</div>');
  }
 }
 
 
 if(obj['msgbox']!=undefined) alert(obj['msgbox']);
 if(obj['location']!=undefined) document.location = obj['location'];
}

function sendAjax(form,response,loader,progress)
{
 var frm = $(form);
 frm.ajaxForm({
  dataType: 'json',
  data: frm.serialize()+'&_ajax=1',
  
  beforeSend: function(){
   $("input[type='submit']").attr('disabled','disabled');
   $(progress).width('0%').parent('.progress').removeClass('hidd');
  },
  
  uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete){
   var pVel = percentComplete + '%';
   $(progress).width(pVel);
  },
  
  complete: function(data){
   recieve(response,unserialize(data));
   $(progress).parent('.progress').addClass('hidd');
   $("input[type='submit']").attr('disabled',null);
  }
 });
 return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="setting_form" action="http://127.0.0.1/marketing/users/setting/" method="post" onsubmit="return sendAjax('#setting_form','#setting_form_result','#setting_form_loader','#setting_form_progress');">
  <input type="hidden" name="_submit" value="1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="data[setting][id]" id="setting_id" value="11" />
  <input type="hidden" name="data[setting][data-token]" id="setting_data-token" value="8022735" />
  <input type="hidden" name="data[setting][token]" id="setting_token" value="90e18fe55fbc38708456606f4b2b3f96" />
  <input type="submit" name="data[setting][submit]" id="setting_submit" value="send" />
  
  <div id="setting_form_progress" class="bar fade"></div>
  <div id="setting_form_result"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: can you try putting alert in your `sendAjax` function to see if it works ?

Comment: yes, ajaxform is not working?

Comment: did u put alert in `sendAjax ` function ??

and when you run no alert came ?? ryt ?

Answer (score 0):

i guess you missing the this library 
http://malsup.com/jquery/form/
 insert the code after
jquery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

Comment: i think there's problem in json
the response code is not correct
it happen to me once and it's doesn't show any error 
just the js stop